# how to search the computer for files and folders

Tags: c++, windows, file

i need a way to search the computer for files like Windows Explorer. i want my program to search lets say hard drive c:. i need it to search C:\ for folders and files (just the ones you could see in c:\ then if the user clicks on a file on the list like the folder test (C:\test) it would search test and let the user see what files/folders are in it.

Comment: And your question is... what?

Comment: This is a platform-specific problem.  Are you on Windows, Unix, etc.?

Comment: If he refers to his hard drive as `C:` and directories as 'folders' it's pretty self evident what his platform might be... ;-)  Oh, and the backslash path separator kind of gives it away also.

Comment: @TreDubZedd: Judging by how many times `C:` was mentioned, I think Windows is a safe bet.

Comment: "Windows Explorer" :D hint hint

Comment: *"like windows explorer"* can also be implemented on other platforms - if it is windows-specific, tag it as such.

Comment: If you want specific file pattern (i.e /usr/share/applications/*.desktop) you can go with this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you mentioned windows, the most straight forward winapi way to do it is with [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(v=VS.85).aspx) functions.

edit: Here's an example that shows you how to enumerate all files/folders in a directory.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_handle=FindFirstFile(L"C:\\*",&file);
    if (search_handle)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout << file.cFileName << std::endl;
        }while(FindNextFile(search_handle,&file));
        FindClose(search_handle);

    }

}
```

Comment: No it finds both. It also allows you to give a search criteria for finding files/folders.

Comment: this gives me "invalid handle" in CloseHandle(). You should use FindClose() instead.

Comment: @NoAngel it seems you are [correct](https://forum.sysinternals.com/handles_topic6054.html), I edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

This will be OS dependent. The SO question

[How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

handles this problem well. You can download [DIRENT](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php) here.

Now that you have this, I'd recommend recursively searching for a file with a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)/[BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. You can assume the whole directory structure is a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_data_structure) where each file is a leaf node and each subdirectory is an internal node.

So all you have to do is,

1. Get the list of files/folders in a directory with a function such as:
   `void getFilesFolders(vector<string> & dir_list, const string & folder_name)`
2. If it's a directory, go to 1 with the directory name
3. If it's a file, terminate if it's the file you're looking for, else move on to the next file.

Comment: How can I get a list of files in a directory using C or C++? is good but the code i can't get to work. only Brian R. Bondy's code the very last one of his but it only finds files part of what i wanted and also i can't find how it works so i can't edit it for my program :(.

Comment: playing with dirent to see if it works get back to you on that

Comment: uhh i can't get dirent i download it but it unzips as a .9 file and thats all. did i miss something because i just downloaded it from your link

Comment: http://www.softagalleria.net/download/dirent/dirent-1.9.zip --- Maybe the .9.zip is confusing your unzip program. I can see a whole VC project here.

Comment: The VC project at that link also has a demo file which prints the contents of a directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Directory` class members to do this with C# or managed C++.  See the following MSDN article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307009

If you wish to use C++ with MFC you can use `CFileFind`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

You'll have to supply your own browse window to present the file system tree.

Or you can use one of the directory/file controls to do both for you.

Comment: That uses .Net and requires using C++/CLI.

Comment: @Georg:  Thanks for the clarification.  I've added additional information in case he wants to use C++ without .NET.

Comment: @blood:  Maybe hit the refresh button.  I added a line about CFileFind and a link to the MSDN doc page.

Comment: i did >_> it did not refresh i guess

Comment: i keep getting errors on all of the code. i don't seem to have the headers i need. i don't have mfc :| i think that might be why all of your code wont compile.

Comment: @blood:  What is your build platform?  Are you using one of the Visual Studio IDE's?

Answer (score 2):

boost::filesystem can be a cross-platform solution for that (check out for such functions in it).

Comment: i did not really want 3rd party software

Comment: Not really 3rd party software so much, boost is virtually considered standard by C++ programmers, but then you don't seem to be one who likes using standard libraries (other than iostream, one of C++'s lesser great features).

Answer (score 2):

```
 #include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int FindF(char* pDirectory)
{
    char szFindPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    strcpy(szFindPath, pDirectory);
    strcat(szFindPath, "\\*");
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_handle=FindFirstFile(szFindPath,&file);
    if (search_handle)
    {
        do
        {
            if(file.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
              strcpy(szFindPath, pDirectory);
              strcat(szFindPath, "\\");
              strcat(szFindPath, file.cFileName);
              FindF(szFindPath);
            }
            std::wcout << file.cFileName << std::endl;
        }while(FindNextFile(search_handle,&file));
        CloseHandle(search_handle);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is nearly a good solution other than: 1. It is mostly in C yet you put in iostream so you are writing in C with iostream... If you want to write in C++ I would at least use std::string. Your real serious blunder is you don't check for "dots" so yours will recurse forever (or more likely suffer from the name of this site).

Comment: Use FindClose() to close handle, opened with FindFirstFile(). CloseHandle() will throw "invalid handle" in debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need to use 3rd party library to accomplish this. This is a short, independent function which lists all files (with their paths) in a directory, including subdiretories' files. `std::string folderName` has to finish with `\`, and if you want to list all files on computer, just create a loop in calling function along with [GetLogicalDriveStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) (It returns strings with `\`, so it couldn't be more convenient in this case).

```
void FindAllFiles(std::string folderName)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
    std::string folderNameWithSt = folderName + "*";
    HANDLE FirstFile = FindFirstFile(folderNameWithSt.c_str(), &FileData);

    if (FirstFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if (strcmp(FileData.cFileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(FileData.cFileName, "..") != 0)
            {
                if(FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                {
                    std::string NewPath = folderName + FileData.cFileName;
                    NewPath = NewPath + "\\";

                    FindAllFiles(NewPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout /*<< folderName*/ << FileData.cFileName << std::endl;
                }
            }
        } while(FindNextFile(FirstFile, &FileData));
    }
}
```

This is ASCII version, remember that files and folders can be named in Unicode

Comment: I'm just wondering, could you explain what are the benefits in comparison to FindFile, please? (and btw, shouldn't it be ASCII oder ANSI?)