# Simple glob in C++ on unix system?

Tags: c++, unix, glob

I want to retrieve all the matching paths following this pattern in a `vector<string>`:

```
"/some/path/img*.png"
```

How can I simply do that ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I have that in my gist. I created a stl wrapper around glob so that it returns vector of string and take care of freeing glob result. Not exactly very efficient but this code is a little more readable and some would say easier to use.

```
#include <glob.h> // glob(), globfree()
#include <string.h> // memset()
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> glob(const std::string& pattern) {
    using namespace std;

    // glob struct resides on the stack
    glob_t glob_result;
    memset(&glob_result, 0, sizeof(glob_result));

    // do the glob operation
    int return_value = glob(pattern.c_str(), GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_result);
    if(return_value != 0) {
        globfree(&glob_result);
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "glob() failed with return_value " << return_value << endl;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
    }

    // collect all the filenames into a std::list<std::string>
    vector<string> filenames;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < glob_result.gl_pathc; ++i) {
        filenames.push_back(string(glob_result.gl_pathv[i]));
    }

    // cleanup
    globfree(&glob_result);

    // done
    return filenames;
}
```

Comment: This does not check for any errors and will leak memory if any of the vector operations throws

Comment: @wakjah i also noticed the lack of error checking (big no-no). so I edited the code and saved it just a moment ago.

Comment: where is the glob.h file?

Comment: @chaohuang `glob.h` is a system header on unix/posix systems. it should be in the same location as other headers such as `stdio.h` etc.

Comment: @wakjah you mind explaining that? They are already calling globfree after populating the vector, and if an error occurred which prevented populating the vector because glob_result.gl_pathc == 0, it won't stop this code from continuing to call globfree() after that check. What you just asked this user to do is a double free, which is a big no-no last I checked. Sure, you could always abruptly abort your application with an error in attempts to prevent a self-crafted double-free, but most people will not want their app to do that.

Comment: I did not ask the user to free the glob twice. At the time I made the comment there was no error checking at all in the posted code. Some error checking has now been added, but the code is still not great as any of the vector `push_back` operations or string constructions in the loop could throw `std::bad_alloc`, which would then cause `glob_result` to be leaked. Ideally since this is C++ we should create a RAII wrapper for `glob_t`, but that's far outside the scope of a comment.

Comment: @wakjah thank you for the clarification. I was sick when posted that and probably wasn't thinking right.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`glob()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) POSIX library function.

Comment: glob() is POSIX not C99, and it does exist on any modern POSIX-compliant UNIX distrubtion.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The point I really was trying to make is that this is a C-style function (producing `char**` and not `std::vector<std::string>` etc.). But it's still the correct function to use when programming in C++. It also should be rather easy to write a wrapper that provides a "C++-style" interface.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to glob a vector of strings, and from what I can see the glob(3) function actually looks in the filesystem...  Is there any library function that does not access the filesystem -- I need it too.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a simple [glob](https://github.com/sryze/glob) library for Windows & Linux (probably works on other *nixes as well) a while ago when I was bored, feel free to use it as you like.

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "glob.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glob::Glob glob(argv[1]);
  while (glob) {
    std::cout << glob.GetFileName() << std::endl;
    glob.Next();
  }
}
```

Comment: This header name will probably conflict on Unix systems if someone is using a build system and includes using <> instead of ""

Answer (score 7):

For newer code to the C++17 standard, `std::filesystem` exists and it can achieve this with `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and the recursive version.  You will have to manually implement the pattern matching. For instance, the C++11 [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library.  This will be portable to any platform with C++17 support.

```
std::filesystem::path folder("/some/path/");
if(!std::filesystem::is_directory(folder))
{
    throw std::runtime_error(folder.string() + " is not a folder");
}
std::vector<std::string> file_list;

for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(folder))
{
    const auto full_name = entry.path().string();

    if (entry.is_regular_file())
    {
       const auto base_name = entry.path().filename().string();
       /* Match the file, probably std::regex_match.. */
       if(match)
            file_list.push_back(full_name);
    }
}
return file_list;
```

A similar API is also implemented in boost for non-C++17 cases.  `std::string::compare()` might be sufficient to find a match, including multiple calls, with `len` and `pos` arguments to match sub-strings only.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the solutions above on Centos6, and I found out that I needed to change:

```
int ret = glob(pat.c_str(), 0, globerr, &glob_result);
```

(where "globerr" is an error handling function)

Without the explicit 0, I got "GLOB_NOSPACE" error.