# How can I find the file by its part of name

Tags: c++, linux, file, find

How can I find the a file by its part of name in c++/linux?
The file full name maybe like:

```
foo.db.1
```

or

```
foo.db.2
```

How can I find the file by part of its name "foo.db", Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Posix standard function for your use case is [`glob()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob).  Earlier somebody posted an easy to use C++ wrapper around it [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system).

Answer (score 2):

For example with:

```
find /your/path -name "foo.db.*"
```

It will match all files in `/your/path` structure whose name is like `foo.db.<something>`.

If the text after `db.` is always a number, you can do:

```
find /your/path -name "foo.db.[0-9]*"
```

You can also use `ls`:

```
ls -l /your/path/ls.db.[0-9]
```

to get files whose name is like `foo.db.<number>` or even

```
ls -l /your/path/ls.db.[0-9]*
```

to get files whose name is like `foo.db.<different numbers>`

Comment: thanks, how to combine it with c++ code? I want to get the full file name in c++

Comment: In fact... People are more curious about how to do it in c++. I guess bash does this for us by running a program multiple times for different files found.

Comment: @fedorqui Till now I know the directory I am searching in, and know the namepattern("foo.db.[0-9]*"), what I want it to know what is the number that at the end of the file name, like if I find "foo.db.13", I would like to know the number is 13, in c++, Thanks

Comment: @user1853170 check [rerx answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19032887/1983854), I think it is a good introduction to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
find /filepath -name "foo.db*"
```

In C/C++, you can do like this:

```
void findFile(const char *path)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    char fileName[] = "foo.db";

    if (!(dir = opendir(path)))
        return;
    if (!(entry = readdir(dir)))
        return;

    do {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
            path[len] = 0;
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;


           if(strstr(fileName, entry->d_name) != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n",  "", entry->d_name);
            }
            findFile(path);
        }
        else
            printf(" %s\n", "", entry->d_name);
    } while (entry = readdir(dir));
    closedir(dir);
}
```