# ls command runnable in terminal not runnable in C++

Tags: c++, linux, ls

I'm trying to run the command `ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}` to get a list of wallpapers, and it runs fine in the terminal, but when I run it from C++ it tells me `ls: cannot access /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}: No such file or directory`. Does anyone know what's up?

The command I used to run it:

```
std::string exec(std::string command) {
    const char *cmd = command.c_str();
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Obviously - it does not expand the `{expression}` and treats it as a file name.

Comment: Maybe you should use the `glob` function instead of a shell command? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system

Comment: Does `/bin/sh` do that expansion OK?  Maybe the `popen()` is running a shell that doesn't do the `{…}` expansion for you.  You might need to run `bash -c "ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}"` instead of just the `ls` command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `exec("/bin/sh -c \"ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}\""` gives the same error.

Comment: @Joe The solution the the question you pointed me at is returning nothing. How should I modify my input?

Comment: `exec`?  I though you used `popen`?  The rules for `exec` are radically different from the rules for `popen`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My `exec` method is using `popen`. I got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c).

Comment: Oh; uggh! Sorry, hadn't noticed that you were preempting a generic name.  OK; I take back the comment.  If you pass `bash -c "…"` (which mustn't contain backslashes when it is printed) and it still fails, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That worked! I got the globing to work too, though, and apparently that's safer, so I'll just use that. Thanks, though!

Comment: Globbing yourself (using the system-provided functions) instead of using `ls` and pipes has a number of merits — go with it.

Comment: I'm now using `std::vector<std::string> walls = glob("/home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.jpg") + glob("/home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.JPG") + glob("/home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.png") + glob("/home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.PNG");` with `glob` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8615450/1526048) and `+` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21391109/1526048).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards like * are evaluated by the shell, so you'll have to invoke the shell directly to if you want it to process something for you.

For example, calling `/bin/sh -c "ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}"` instead of `ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}` will work. There is also a system call called `system()` that invokes a given command in the default shell for you.

However, using the shell to do the globbing is [very dangerous](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2130132) if you pass untrusted user input to the shell. So try listing all the files and then using a native globbing solution to filter them instead of shell expansions.

Comment: I'm pretty new to c++, what is globbing?

Comment: Globbing is the expansion of the 'glob' (`*`) in file names, and more generally, filename expansion.

Comment: Huh. I'll look into the comment about the `glob` function. Also, `exec("/bin/sh -c \"ls /home/aidan/Pictures/Wallpapers/*/*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}\""` gives the same error.

Comment: Concerning your question what globbing is, just search the web, @AidanEdwards: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=globbing. Concerning the error, what is the output if you run the command without `exec()`, i.e. outside of C++?

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards like "*" or "{x,y,z}" are evaluated by the shell. If you run a program without intermediate shell, those are not evaluated but passed verbatim to the program, which should explain the error message.