# How to get all images in folder using c++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0

I have a problem. I'm writing C++ with the openCV library. I want to get the number of all images in a folder and I want to load all images in the folder for process in C++.

Comment: Here is the [possible duplicate topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use [glob](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gaf91b7f383218e2d3f760939140942297) to get a list of filenames:

```
vector<cv::String> fn;
glob("/home/images/*.png", fn, false);

vector<Mat> images;
size_t count = fn.size(); //number of png files in images folder
for (size_t i=0; i<count; i++)
    images.push_back(imread(fn[i]));
```

Comment: thank for answer. If I will show an image fn[ i ] .
I write imshow("picture",fn[ i ]);  or imshow("pic",image);
between for(...) and images.push_back .it not work fine for me.

Comment: I understand to show an image by change type of count from size_t to int 
thank you berak :D

Comment: @Nungning Works Perfectly fine for any kind of vector variable, Thank you

Comment: I am getting assertion faild in debug mode and idies why ?