# Command line argument like user input in c++

Tags: c++, c, command-line

In command line argument like `./a.out echo *` the `*` will be changed by the terminal so that all the files in the directory can be printed. What I want is that standard input do the same thing.

Is there any way of doing this in C++? Any help will be thanked.

Comment: `int main()` can accept command line arguments

Comment: Are you quite sure that the command line arguments `"echo"` and `"*"` are passed to the program as anything else but `"echo"` and `"*"`?

Comment: The terminal actually does not perform any magic here. It is the *program* that is responsible for interpreting the wild-card character `*`. Your program can do it, too. Use the `argc` and `argv` parameters passed by your environment to your program's `main` function. Those contain the command-line arguments used to invoke your program.

Comment: yes, I have found that out unexpectedly. I used command line argument `./a.out echo *` and wrote a method for doing a simple echo (just printing whatever is passed after echo) and all the files and folders of that particular directory is printed. I want that, but in standard input.

Comment: In Unix and LInux and such the shell does expand wildcards and the program doesn't ever see them (it sees the matched results). On Windows it's the job of the program ran to expand wildcards (if that's what it chooses to do with those characters). I would suggest fans of the Unix approach read unix haters handbook The Unix Haters Handbook.

Comment: I want that in linux, not in windows. But I want that wildcard expanding feature in standard input. Is that possible? @steve

Comment: Then you expand them yourself.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html

Comment: Are you looking to read the file names from stdin, i.e. using something like `scanf` `fgets` to read the filenames?

Comment: You can let the shell do it for you. From within c++ you can grab the argument ('a*' for example) from argv, and you could issue a system command concatenating "ls " with your wild card. There are solutions here at stack overflow to read the returned output of a system command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

you could write:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    printf("Element %d : '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Note: If you want to do this steps in C please have a look here [Simple glob in C++ on unix system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system)

Comment: I am pretty familiar  with command line arguments. My question was, is it possible to do wildcard expanding in standard input like that of command line input? @Roby

Comment: @smashingpumpkin, oh sorry i misunderstand the question, have a look at glob

Comment: glob would probably do my work. Thank you.