# How to use glob in c++ if I have an parent folder and on child folder?

Tags: c++

how to use glob if I have a parent folder and an child folder and I want to read from each all files.

From example if I have folder Results and into folder Results I have  `5 folders`, `Results1`, `Results2` ... `Results5` and in each folder I have more images how to read in order each pictures, from `Result1` after `Result2` ...

How to make it using glob, or you have another suggestion, for example how to storage all name of file from folder Results ?

Thanks!

Comment: I get the impression you are trying to do something like what is being discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].