# Read files with path given as pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, filesystems

```
pwd
    A1.txt
```

I want to do this.

```
std::ifstream in("A*.txt");
```

Is there any method of doing this?

Comment: You can use [`glob.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/glob.h.html) to [gather files using wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401777/simple-glob-in-c-on-unix-system)

Comment: please add more context to the problem and do clean up the "REad" in your title

Comment: @PasserBy, There is nothing to add. Currently I am not able to read the files. It is the only matching file btw

Answer (score 1):

There is no filename matching functionality in the C++ standard library.

POSIX provides the `glob` function in the `glob.h` header. Non-POSIX systems may have their own API for filename matching which may or might not differ from POSIX in behaviour.

If you cannot rely on non (C++) standard functionality, then you could of course implement filename matching yourself. However, prior to the upcoming C++17 standard, there is no way to get the file listing of a directory using the C++ standard library, so until then you have to rely on a platform specific API (or a wrapper library).